# Can Netbeans auto-create Symfony2 projects?

Tags: php, netbeans, symfony

Just giving Symfony a test-drive, and I'm really falling for Netbeans.  Seems like a good combo, although I'm a rookie with both.

According to some tutorials and informational webpages (like [this one](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/symfony-screencast.html)), Symfony 1.x has a "symfony" script which, among other things, Netbeans uses to automatically generate Symfony projects, including front- and back-ends.

Does Symfony2 have the same capability, or will it after it reaches gold master?  Otherwise, what strategies are there for integrating Symfony2 with Netbeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. Maybe in a future release of netbeans. Symfony2 is too young.

edit 16 december 2011 :
netbeans symfony2 support has started :
http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/initial_support_for_symfony2

Comment: is it worth it, then, to use SF1.4 instead?

Comment: @niteshade: No, symfony2 has a script as well. It's only lacking of IDE support, but you can easily use in directly in the shell.

Comment: @hakre, where is the script?  I don't see it in /bin/ or /app/

Comment: @niteshade: Please re-read the symfony2 installation instructions. They contain the guide to the scripts. It varies where you install symfony2.

Comment: Of course symfony2 can be initialized by a console command. But, I thinked the question was about native integration of symfony2 in netbeans...